# Want to know difference b/w this.parent; this.parentApplication; this.parentDocument;

Tags: apache-flex, popup

What is the difference between these three:

```
this.parent;
this.parentApplication;
this.parentDocument;
```

when i call this in a popupWindow.

Addition to this: I have a tabnavigator as a  Custom component. When I click some Button on tabnavigator, the popup(titlewindow) will display. Now I want to call a function defined in the tabnavigator from popup(titlewindow). Suggest some ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure with the this.parent but confirm with this.parentApplication and this.parentDocument

let's take a tree of that for easy understand.

```
                     1
                    / \
                   2   3
                  /|\   \
                 4 5 6   7
                    \     \
                     8     9
```

1 - ParentDocument:1 - ParentApplication:1

2 - ParentDocument:1 - ParentApplication:1

3 - ParentDocument:1 - ParentApplication:1

4 - ParentDocument:2 - ParentApplication:1

5 - ParentDocument:2 - ParentApplication:1

6 - ParentDocument:2 - ParentApplication:1

7 - ParentDocument:3 - ParentApplication:1

8- ParentDocument:5 - ParentApplication:1

9 - ParentDocument:7 - ParentApplication:1

Answer (score 1):

Generate an event from your child popup that the application is listening for. Children shouldn't know anything about their parents.

Comment: I have used Events which are working perfectly. I was trying without generating event communicate with parent. so `this.parentDocument` will worked. dont know which one is better.

Comment: If you want something slightly different to happen in a different part of your application in response to the same thing happening in the View, then you'll have to branch in the View (based on some condition that will probably need to read from the parent, according to your design), then call a function that you will have to write in the parent and refer to in the View. With an Event, nothing needs to happen different in the View. Now imagine that you want to reuse the View in another application, and things get even more complicated.